# Wix4: Undefined preprocessor $(Configuration)

Tags: wix4

I have a `wix3` project that creates an msi file that works fine from VS and from the msbuild cli. I decided to start playing with `wix4` and check if I can grab some of its advantages soon in the future.

After converting my `wix3` project to the new `wix4` format and after stripping the wixproj file to the minimum in order to simplify things I can build from VS the project and I get a valid `.msi` setup but when running it via `powershell` with the `wix build` I'm getting this error:

> error WIX0150: Undefined preprocessor variable '$(Configuration)'

I'm aware that some variables are automatically set by the `msbuild` tasks, but how to connect or define them now that I would like to use the `wix build` command?

Here some stuff I have tried:

I see in the [wix build command documentation](https://wixtoolset.org/docs/reference/wixexe/#build) that with the `-define` or `-d` I can set a preprocessor variable I guess using it like this:

> wix build -o product.msi src/myproject.wixproj -d:Configuration=Debug (or -d=Configuration=Debug)

but I get this error:

> wix.exe : error WIX0118: Additional argument '-d=Configuration=Debug' was unexpected. Remove the argument and add the '-?' switch for more information.

Syntax is wrong for sure but I could not find any example and wix build -? does not give any extra info or examples.

Also digging in the documentation I see in the [preprocessor variables](https://wixtoolset.org/docs/reference/msbuild/project-references/#preprocessor-variables) that I can get Configuration like this: `ProjectName.Configuration` in my case would be `myproject.Configuration`, but if I substitute it in the wixproj file I get the same initial error, here the usage of the problematic preprocessor variable:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
  <DefineConstants>Debug;SourceFilesDir=C:\ProgramData\myProgram_dev</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">
  <DefineConstants>Release;SourceFilesDir=C:\ProgramData\myProgram</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I guess I'm missing some basics here... sorry if all my explanation seems a chaos, please, feel free to let me know if I can improve it in the comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is `-d name=value` with a space separating the `-d` switch from the name and value.

Comment: That solved the error about the preprocessor variable, great and thanks!